# Can I Browserify nodejs ws module so browser becomes the server side of a Web Socket connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, browserify

We all know Web Sockets API as implemented in browsers is client side only ... however if I [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) the nodejs [ws module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) and run it browser side can it act as a server in a Web Sockets connection ?

Comment: looks like we can now run any nodejs package from a browser :  http://blog.tonicdev.com/2015/09/30/embedded-tonic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browserify `ws` module relies on C++ code built with `node-gyp`. No, you cannot use `browserify` to convert it to client-side Javascript. (Unless `ws` has some conditional compilation for builds under `browserify`.)

Anyway, let's think about it in a realistic way. Client-side Javascript interacts with the world via a limited API, which doesn't contain anything resembling Websocket server or TCP support. No, you cannot create a Websocker server on a client.